# How to export a list of addresses that email in my spam folder was sent to?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention, export

With a Gmail username@gmail.com address, you'll also receive email sent to username+label@gmail.com addresses, very handy for creating filters.

I often username+website@gmail.com when signing up to websites, so if I end up getting lots of spam sent to that address, I know who to blame.

But what's a good way to find a list of all username+anything@ addresses in my Gmail spam folder?

I'd prefer to do this within the web client if possible. Next best is using external client such as Outlook or Opera mail but without having to download lots of mail if possible. I don't really want to download spam emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I made a simple Python script.

Using `imaplib` and `email`, it gets a list of emails in your `[Gmail]/Spam` folder, and lists those containing `username+` in the "To" field.

Get it here:

https://github.com/hugovk/gmail/blob/master/spamify.py

Comment: @pnuts Accepted!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it can be done on the web client as it strips away all labels when a message goes into the spam folder.

As for not wanting to DL a bunch of spam, I'd use IMAPv4 instead of POP in your preferred e-mail client. All messages stay on the server, it just downloads headers.